# Unity Animator doesnt show what animation is active now

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, progress-bar, animator

I thought that in this window I supposed to be able to see a bar that shows what animation is currently been played but It doesn't appear and I don´t know why. help

[Image about the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN0Lo.png)

Comment: Is there an animation clip attached to that state?

Comment: Yes! Actually the animation works, i mean the sprite moves making the correct animation. But when I got a problem It was so difficult to me understand what animation was currently active.

Comment: ReplyTo @derHugo